# Trying to get javascript to animate a canvas element on the click of a button. But the canvas shows itself for a second and then disappears.

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, html5-canvas

The code I'm using is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>I don't know</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>What do you want? Max Limit. 100 X 100 . 0 for white. 1 for black. enter for newline</p>
 <form id="main">
<input type="text" name="string"><br>
<button onclick="drawBoard()">Click Me</button>
</form> 

<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="420px" height="420px" style="background: #fff; margin:20px"></canvas>
 <script>
    function drawBoard(){
var bw = 400;
// Box height
var bh = 400;
// Padding
var p = 0;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
for (var x = 0; x <= bw; x += 40) {
context.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
context.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, bh + p);
 }


for (var x = 0; x <= bh; x += 40) {
context.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
context.lineTo(bw + p, 0.5 + x + p);
}

context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();
}

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the button, the grid shows itself for a second and then disappears. What is causing the issue?
When I opened console view, I saw an error stating "Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’: The target origin provided (‘null’) does not match the recipient window’s origin (‘null’)."

Comment: Delete the form or put the button out of form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a form, the page will reload as part of the submit process. You either need to prevent this default behavior with JavaScript...

```
 function drawBoard(e){
  e.preventDefault() // stops default form submission
  ...
 }
```

or just remove that `form` element. For just a button click with no inputs, a form is not needed.